# Line break Twilio API PHP

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I'm using Twilio api in php with native library and I tried many solutions from stackoverflow or from their official website but none of them is working. please think before marking it as already answered. I'm providing some proofs that its really not working. please help if I'm missing some headers etc. because i tried official solution and it doesn't work.

```
$sid="xxxxxxxxxxx";
$token="xyxxxcxc";
    $client=new Client($sid, $token);

     function Send_Message($client, $msg, $to){

      return $client->messages->create(

        $to,

        array('from' => '+12566661887',

          'body'=>$msg

       )

      );

    }
```

[Please check this image all possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSAOn.jpg)

Comment: Show us where `$msg` is set, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit hex code replacement and escape sequences, such as \r or \n, will be output literally.

(http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

This will not work

```
array(
    'from' => $twilio_number,
    'body' => 'I sent \r\n this message in under 10 minutes!'
)
```

---

instead use double quotes, **this should work**

```
array(
    'from' => $twilio_number,
    'body' => "I sent \r\n this message in under 10 minutes!"
)
```

---

or with **`$msg`**

`$msg = "I sent \r\n this message in under 10 minutes!";`

---

```
array(
    'from' => $twilio_number,
    'body' => $msg
)
```

Comment: It *might* be this, but we don't know `$msg` has single-quoted `\n` marks from what OP posted.

Comment: Thank you  so much. I was using single quotes. Thanks for help.